# Py2exe RuntimeError

Tags: python, runtime-error, py2exe

I was trying to "compile" my python app with py2exe as I have made the last times and this time, it returns me: `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`.
I haven't changed the version of py2exe or imported more libraries to my app or the main script, but from now on, it seems that it won't compile.
My setup script is this:

`options  ={
        'py2exe': {
            'bundle_files' : 3,
            'includes':[r'scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation',
                         r'scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx','scipy.linalg.cython_blas',
                         'scipy.linalg.cython_lapack','scipy.integrate',
                         'matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg','tkinter.filedialog',
                         'cv2','pygame.camera','scipy','scipy.ndimage','matplotlib.pyplot',
                         'scipy.misc','ast','urlparse','six'],
            'excludes': ['six.moves.urllib.parse'],
            'packages' : ['encodings'],
            }
        },
    zipfile = None,`

I have been trying some of the solutions the people have written on some forums and here like:

- Add six.moves.urllib.parse to the "exclude" in the setup.py script (I read that there is a problem with this library that causes a loop.)
- Import sys in setup.py and add this lines

  `import sys
  sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)`

But nothing works...
Anyone can help me?
Thanks

Comment: I made the correct edits and post my code. Thanks.

Comment: I have been changing the imports to my code and the problem is with the mathplotlib libraries, but I need it to run correctly the program, any suggestion?

Comment: I have solved the problems from matplotlib... I think there's a problem with this library... So I made another dummy script and try to compile.
With matplotlib, it returns me the same error, without it, it compile correctly.
So I remove matplotlib from my main script and from now on, it returns me another error. `File: C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py TypeError: source code string cannot contain null bytes`